# Can arrow keys be added to an iPhone keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard

Is there a way to add arrow keys to an iPhone keyboard under iOS 6?

Comment: Any Bluetooth keyboard lets you use arrow keys as well as many navigation shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Looking for a way to change the default touchscreen keyboard, however

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible on a jailbroken device, but not on with standard iOS. There are just no user configurable options for the keyboard, beyond adding additional languages. App developers can augment it slightly, and there are some apps with additional keys, such as [Prompt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115) and [Textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com/), but it's otherwise a standard system component that can't be changed.

Comment: If you have clumsy fingers, how are you supposed to properly navigate to a former place in a text block? A lot of deleting?

Comment: My original question asked this but was edited out:  is there an app that offers a different system wide keyboard? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: @Nick_B That second question was edited out since we prefer one question per question. It's fine to ask that second question and link here in case robmathers has an idea...

Comment: Okay. I considered it to be a subset of original question (is there a way to add arrow keys), as in maybe that is a way to solve the issue of needing arrow keys on iphone.  But whatever is best. Will follow up later. Thank you