# Can you add arrow keys to an iOS 15 keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, development

I am using GitPod, an in-browser IDE, in iOS Safari on my iPhone SE 2.

I would like to be able to enter up, down, left and right arrow key input to move the cursor in the IDE’s terminal and to retrieve previous commands from the shell.

This SE post from 2012 says that there is no way to modify the iOS keyboard: [Can arrow keys be added to an iPhone keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70596/can-arrow-keys-be-added-to-an-iphone-keyboard).

Have things changed since then? Is there any good “Hacker’s Keyboard” for iOS or is there in theory a way to make one given the iOS development tools?

Comment: Why arrow keys to move cursor? Tap and hold spacebar and move cursor left-right-up-down.

Comment: The above answer is incorrect e.g typefinity.
It does not have up and down arrow keys so their description is misrepresenting their functionality. The other answer here about the space bar does not work in the context of using say a terminal editor that requires up and down keys and other keys like CTRL so beware of keyboards that say arrow keys they may not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative keyboards have been available for iOS since iOS 8 in 2014, there are tons of them in the App Store.  That's the place to look for one with arrows.   An [example](https://typefinity.com).